# SipManager.newInstance not working for android Gingerbread

Tags: android, android-emulator, sip

I am trying to run a simple SIP program using android 2.3 emulator.

When i am trying to create an instance of SipManager i get a return value as null(which means the SIP API isn't supported).

Pls suggest how i can test SIP in emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working for me thanks to the Issues list link below :

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13037

and the thing which worked for me is in sub link in this thread.

### How to enable SIP in Android 2.3 emulator.

1. Make the system partition writeable. Open a cmd window and enter these:

emulator -avd  -partition-size 128
adb shell mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock1 /system

1. Enable SIP support:

Copy 2 XMLs from AOSP into text files: android.software.sip.xml, android.software.sip.voip.xml, and copy XMLs to the emulator:

adb push android.software.sip.voip.xml /system/etc/permissions
adb push android.software.sip.xml /system/etc/permissions

1. Disable config_sip_wifi_only in config.xml: false

The repacked resource file can be found here. Copy it to the emulator:

adb push framework-res.apk /system/framework

1. Close emulator and start it again in normal mode.

Or... these steps in one: download the AVD system.img and copy into the ....android\avd\.avd folder.

Known issue: incoming calls are not working yet.

Comment: `PANIC:Could not open : -partion -size`